# Find the equation of the locus of $Q$

Tags: geometry, circles, locus

[image]

In the figure, $C$ is a variable circle of radius $1$. Let $G(u,v)$ be the center of the circle, parallelogram $OPQR$ is tangent to the circle at the point $R$, and circle cuts the $x$-axis at point $P$.

How to express coordinates of $P,Q,R$ in terms of $u,v$ and more importantly, how to find the locus of $Q$?

---

Edit: How to find the $\textbf{equation}$ of locus of $Q$?

Comment: Draw a perpendicular from Q onto the x- axis, call that S. How long is PS? Moreover, since R is point of tangency, the coordinates of R depend on G

Comment: Thanks for hints!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the circle always passes through the origin, here is a proposed solution.

Observe that the tangent $RQ$ is a horizontal tangent and horizontal tangents are possible only at points directly above and below centre on the circle. Therefore, coordinates of $R$ are $(u,1+v)$. Also, perpendicular from centre bisects a chord, therefore, $P$ is $(2u,0)$. Now, $OP=QR$, hence, $Q$ is $(3u,1+v)$.

Also, distance of centre from origin is $1$, so, $u^2+v^2=1$.

So, locus of $Q$ is an ellipse.

Hope it helps:)

Comment: Unbelievable. I thought I would have to write plenty of equations. Now, when I look at the picture and read what you wrote, it's so easy to understand. And yes, the locus of $Q$ is an ellipse $x^2 + 9y - 18y = 0$. Hope that I won't struggle to get to that point :)

Comment: Do you mind if I undo acceptance of the answer so that somebody can help me in getting the equation of the locus? Or maybe you can give me a hint

Comment: I don't understand what is remaining now. Coordinates of $Q$ are $(3u,1+v)$ and using the last equation we get $u^2+v^2=1\Longrightarrow (\frac{x}{3})^2+(y-1)^2=1\Longrightarrow x^2+9y-18=0$